# codeigniter:everything created through MVC pattern?

Tags: codeigniter

I'm studying codeigniter and I would realize a simple application. I'm asking if every page, even if doesn't not contain directly dynamic element must be create through MVC pattern? I explain myself: my home page will not contain anything of dinamic. only an header, menu and footer. it needs to create model,controller and view to handle this situation or I create simple the home page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You always have to create a controller because that is what is called from the url.

As far as the view and model.  You don't always have to create either.

I've got plenty of pages with static info so I don't need any model interaction at all.

Without a view you are kind of defeating the purpose of the MVC.  It is possible for the controller to just echo all your html for the page but I wouldn't do it.

The way I do it is that I have a default view that contains the header and footer.  A content view that all my content for the page goes into.  I then pump my view for the page into the content view then that into the default view to create my page.

```
$arrData["vwsContent"] = $this->load->view("your view for the page", $arrData, TRUE);
$arrData["vwsPageContent"] = $this->load->view("content template view", $arrData, TRUE);
$this->load->view("default template view", $arrData, FALSE);
```

In this way I can have different content views but the same default view for all the pages.  For instance my homepage looks different than my regular pages so I would have a HOME template to use instead of a CONTENT template.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the home page function in any controller.

In routes.php the default controller and action can be defined

`$route['default_controller'] = "welcome";` (welcome can be replaced by any your prefer controller) .

Create function with name index

```
function index(){
        $this->load->view('index');
}
```

Then create the file index.php in "views" folder.

In index.php you can put all your HTML static content. You can use URL helper [ function base_url()] for images/css/js path.